# Name - Combine 'Atiyatullah' and 'Amatul Aala' to make proper name

Tags: arabic-translation, naming

I'm not an Arabic speaker but I'd like to use both words for my daughter name as I found both words beautiful.
Is it possible and/or common to create a name like "A gift (from Allah) **who will become** the servant (of The Highest One)"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot combine two mudaf ilaihi. It is like combining Gift of Allah and Servant of Allah, the result would be Gift and Servant of Allah. You will have to bring the waw particle to separate two mudaf.

Can you combine Abdur-rahman and Abdur-raheem? Answer is No. Because you cannot combine two mudaf ilaihi